# How to query connected coordinates?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I map values based on X and Y coordinates (XY are primary keys)

```
+---+---+--------+--------+
| X | Y | Data 1 | Data 2 |
+---+---+--------+--------+
```

Let's say that I have that values stored there:

```
    X →
    1234567
Y 1|XXXX  X|
↓ 2| XX   X|
  3|    X X|
  4| X   XX|
  5| X XXXX|
```

How do I build a SQL query to fetch all connected values as result? The fetch order is not important.

For example, if I query for:

- `X=3` and `Y=2` it fetches: `(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(2,2),(3,2)`
- `X=5` and `Y=3` it fetches: `(5,3)`
- `X=2` and `Y=4` it fetches: `(2,4),(2,5)`
- `X=7` and `Y=3` it fetches: `(4,5),(5,5),(6,4),(6,5),(7,1),(7,2),(7,3),(7,4),(7,5)`

The example table as SQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `x` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `y` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`x`,`y`)
);
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES
(1, 0),(1, 1),(2, 2),(2, 4),(2, 5),(3, 1),(3, 2),(4, 1),(4, 5),
(5, 0),(5, 5),(6, 4),(6, 5),(7, 1),(7, 2),(7, 3),(7, 4),(7, 5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with SQL. You need to load the data into a 2D boolean matrix and implement a search algorithm. You start with a point and recursively search in all 8 directions and add items with an X to a Set. Stop when an empty spot is found.

This is somewhat similar to an area filling algorithm in a paint program.

You could search in the database directly by issuing individual SQLs to each coordinate, but it wouldn't be very effective.

Answer (score 2):

What you asked can be achieved through a common table expression.

I am using TSQL in this example, but similar queries can be built using other SQL dialects.

Lets first start with a view that lists all the adjacent cells:

```
create view [dbo].[fromto] as
select
t1.x as x_from, 
t1.y as y_from,
t2.x as x_to,
t2.y as y_to
from test t1
join test t2 on t2.x = t1.x and t2.y = t1.y + 1
union
select
t1.x as x_from, 
t1.y as y_from,
t2.x as x_to,
t2.y as y_to
from test t1
join test t2 on t2.x = t1.x and t2.y = t1.y - 1
union
select
t1.x as x_from, 
t1.y as y_from,
t2.x as x_to,
t2.y as y_to
from test t1
join test t2 on t2.x = t1.x + 1 and t2.y = t1.y
union
select
t1.x as x_from, 
t1.y as y_from,
t2.x as x_to,
t2.y as y_to
from test t1
join test t2 on t2.x = t1.x - 1 and t2.y = t1.y
```

Now we have to recursively iterate through this view:

```
with walk (x_col_from, y_col_from, x_col_to, y_col_to, stack ) as(
select 
x_from, 
y_from, 
x_to, 
y_to, 
cast(concat('|',x_from ,',',y_from, '|', x_to, ',', y_to) as varchar)
from fromto
union all
select 
walk.x_col_from, 
walk.y_col_from, 
fromto.x_to, 
fromto.y_to,
cast(concat(walk.stack,'|',fromto.x_to,',',fromto.y_to) as varchar)
from fromto
join walk on walk.x_col_to = fromto.x_from and walk.y_col_to = fromto.y_from 
where CHARINDEX(cast(concat('|',fromto.x_to,',',fromto.y_to) as varchar), walk.stack) = 0
)
select * from walk
```

The stack field is used to memoize the cells we have already visited. It also gives the path through the grid.

Comment: Wow.. now that's a sophisticated set of queries you present here. +1\

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with some recursive** SQL path search in 4 directions, but I feel you can't do it in a *single* query.. from any X'd point, you can use a query step around in 4 directions and if X'es are found, use a recursive invoke of the same query to investigate the context of that target.. but you will want to avoid circular loops and flipping between neighbours. In every WHERE, a filter of "covered positions sofar" is needed. And you will find only one of the groups on each go. To find all groups, you would need to run more queries.

To avoid too many tests, I'd put a band of empty cells along the border of the square field and iterate over 1..N-2 instead of 0..N-1.

Platform: the work *can* be done with queries in a stored procedure. But rather I would consider *not* to use SQL for this. It might be more convenient to use a CLR-call, with large part of the problem coded in c#. You can implement a function referring to your classlib DLL, from a stored procedure.

****** did not look at the tags ! in MySql there is no recursive select.. so the answer is "no" anyway